# How should i reduce these boilerplates to handel Network Response in Android using retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

This is my ViewModle class methods

```
    private fun handleResponse(response: Response<OtpSentDataClass>): Resource<OtpSentDataClass> {
    if (response.isSuccessful) {
        response.body()?.let { otpSentResponse ->
            return Resource.Success(otpSentResponse)
        }
    } else {
        val body =
            Gson().fromJson(response.errorBody()?.charStream(), ErrorBodyResponse::class.java)
        when {
            response.code() == 400 -> {
                return (Resource.Failure(Constants.error400, body?.message))
            }
            response.code() == 401 -> {
                return (Resource.Failure(Constants.error401, body?.message))
            }
            response.code() == 403 -> {
                return (Resource.Failure(Constants.error403, body?.message))
            }
            ...
            response.code() == 408 -> {
                return (Resource.Failure(Constants.error408, body?.message))
            }
            ...
            ...
            response.code() == 413 -> {
                return (Resource.Failure(Constants.error413, body?.message))
            }
            ...
            response.code() == 511 -> {
                return (Resource.Failure(Constants.error511, body?.message))
            }
            else -> {
                return Resource.Failure("Something went wrong ${body?.message}")
            }
        }
    }
    val body = Gson().fromJson(
        response.errorBody()?.charStream(),
        ErrorBodyResponse::class.java
    )
    return Resource.Failure("Something went wrong ${body?.message}")
}
```

similarly i have other methods in this same viewmodle
like

```
private fun handleDeviceDetailResponse(response: Response<DeviceDetailResponse>): Resource<DeviceDetailResponse>
private fun handleVerifyResponse(response: Response<VerifyOtpResponse>): Resource<VerifyOtpResponse>
```

Now the problem is I have many other viewmodels which has these kind of handle response methods, which creates lots of boilerplate.

*How should I keep my code clean?*

Comment: you can do it via interceptor (https://square.github.io/okhttp/features/interceptors/#interceptors)

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii Suggested a great solution. You can also model your app a bit better. Create a repository layer to handle the API access, Making the ViewModel agnostic to where it is receiving the data from. More about it here:  https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture

Answer (score 1):

I would put your error codes in a map, so you can retrieve them by number. I don't know what type your constants are, so I'm just treating them as Strings as an example.

```
object Constants {

    //...

    private val errorCodes = mapOf(
        400 to "bad_request",
        401 to "unauthorized",
        // etc.
    )

    const val UNSPECIFIED_ERROR_CODE_STRING

    fun errorCodeToString(code: Int): String = errorCodes[code] ?: UNSPECIFIED_ERROR_CODE_STRING
}
```

Then you can use your function in you application code. Also, your code is tripping over nullability because you separately check `isSuccessful` and then get your `body()`. `body()` is non-null if and only if `isSuccessful` is true, so there's no reason to check `isSuccessful`. Your code as written forces you to write a redundant branch of failure code at the bottom that will never be reached.

```
private fun handleResponse(response: Response<OtpSentDataClass>): Resource<OtpSentDataClass> {
    response.body()?.let { otpSentResponse ->
        return Resource.Success(otpSentResponse)
    }
    // We can assert non-null errorBody, because body and errorBody are never both null
    val errorBody = Gson().fromJson(response.errorBody()!!.charStream(), ErrorBodyResponse::class.java)
    val errorCode = Constants.errorCodeToString(response.code())
    return when (errorCode) {
        UNSPECIFIED_ERROR_CODE_STRING -> Resource.Failure("Something went wrong ${errorBody?.message}")
        else -> Resource.Failure(errorCode, errorBody?.message)
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect, but what should i write for cont val UNSPECIFIED_ERROR_CODE_STRING = ?????